# java - How to update members in the hierarchy using reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I have a class called Volvo that inherits from car.
It contains a class called Engine that contains Valve.

```
public class Engine {

    public Engine(int e, int f) {
        this.e = e;
        valve = new Valve(f);
    }

    private int e;
    private Valve valve;
}
```

valve has a single data member - int f;

```
public class Valve {
    public Valve(int f) {
        this.f = f;
    }

    public int f;
}
```

Everything is private and does not contain a setter.

I want to set a value using reflection with the following string

```
fillIn(volvo, "Engine.Valve.f", 10);
```

Using this code:

```
String[] splits = path.split("\\.");
Class tmpClass = obj.getClass();

for (int i = 0; i < splits.length; i++) {
    if (i + 1 != splits.length) {
        Field field = tmpClass.getDeclaredField(splits[i]);
        tmpClass = field.getClass();
    } else {
        System.out.println("**** - " + splits[i]);
    }
}
```

Problems:
1. My object is Volvo. the engine is located at car. can I get the field when iterating on volvo.  
2. How do I set the value? the type is different every time. 
3. Is there a better practice (FW?) that can do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you avoiding the use of setters and getter? The problem would be so simple.

Comment: Why is it easier? Please look at my answer. Would it be more simple if getters where required?

Comment: Easier by far. What you have done in 10 lines of code could be done in one. Also the methods obfuscate the intention of what is trying to be done. See my alternate answer below

Comment: Thanks. But I asked about reflection( asked for an example where I am not familiar with the class beforehand).

Answer (score 1):

To access private field, you can set access to `true` on field like this:

```
field.setAccessible(true);
```

Look at this example:
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/private-fields-and-methods.html
and javadoc
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#setAccessible(boolean)

---

BTW using setters will be surely better

---

EDIT:
You need to store object of the field to set:
A bit edited code, written by javadoc and not tested

```
String[] splits = path.split("\\.");
Class tmpClass = obj.getClass();
Object tmpObject = obj;

for (int i = 0; i < splits.length; i++) {
    if (i + 1 != splits.length) {
        Field field = tmpClass.getDeclaredField(splits[i]);
        tmpClass = field.getClass();
        if(tmpClass.equals(Integer.class)){
            field.setInt(tmpObject,42); //where 42 is the number to set
            return;
        }
        tmpObject = field.get(tmpObject); // tmpObject contais the object to set
    }
}
```

Maybe code wont work, but I hope it shows the idea

Comment: I have set it as accessible earlier. It doesn't solve my set issue.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it without need for access level or getters & setters using
(this needs to rewrite for production + it only solvves for an int currently)

```
private static void fillIn(Object obj, String path, int value) {
        Object tempObj = obj;
        ReflectionData reflectionData;
        if (path.contains(".")) {
            String[] splits = path.split("\\.");

            for (int i = 0; i < splits.length; i++) {
                reflectionData = getReflectionData(tempObj, splits[i]);
                if (i + 1 != splits.length) {
                    tempObj = reflectionData.getFieldObject();
                } else {
                    reflectionData.setFieldObject(value);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static ReflectionData getReflectionData(Object obj, String fieldName) {
        ReflectionData reflectionData = null;

        Class tmpClass = obj.getClass();
        while (tmpClass != null) {
            Field[] declaredFields = tmpClass.getDeclaredFields();
            for (Field field : declaredFields) {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                if (field.getName().equals(fieldName)){
                    reflectionData = new ReflectionData(tmpClass, field, obj);
                }
            }
            tmpClass = tmpClass.getSuperclass();
        }
        return reflectionData;
    }
```

where

public class ReflectionData {

```
public ReflectionData(Class<?> aClass, Field field, Object object) {
    this.aClass = aClass;
    this.field = field;
    this.object = object;
}

public Class<?> aClass;
public Field field;
public Object object;

public Object getFieldObject() {
    Object o = null;
    try {
        o = field.get(object);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return o;
}

public void setFieldObject(int value) {
    try {
        field.set(object, value);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You are moving towards the right direction, there are however a couple of issues in your code:

1. As you already discovered, `getDeclaredField` will get a field for you if it is declared in the class you are calling it on and not if it is declared in the superclass. You can however use the `NoSuchFieldException` which will get thrown if the field is not declared in the current class in order to get the superclass and try again.
2. When attempting to get fields by reflection the value you pass to the `getDeclaredField` method is case sensitive. This means that you will need to call the `fillIn` method as `fillIn(volvo, "engine.valve.f", 10);` since the Volvo class has (through inheritance of the Car class) a field named `engine`, not `Engine`.
3. `tmpClass = field.getClass();` will retrieve the class of the `field` object, which is of course `Field`. What you want to do is retrieve the type of the declared field represented by `field`, which can be done with `field.getType()`.

Your code therefore becomes:

```
private void fillIn(Object obj, String path, int number) throws Exception {
    String[] splits = path.split("\\.");
    Class tmpClass = obj.getClass();

    for (int i = 0; i < splits.length; i++) {
        if (i + 1 != splits.length) {
            Field field = null;
            while ((field == null) && (tmpClass != null)) {
                try {
                    field = tmpClass.getDeclaredField(splits[i]);
                } catch (NoSuchFieldException ex) {
                    tmpClass = tmpClass.getSuperclass();
                }
            }
            tmpClass = field.getType();
        } else {
            System.out.println("**** - " + splits[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative answer showing how easy it would be if getters and setters were used.

```
// Assuming that the Volvo class builds it own engine,
// with the Engine class building its own value.
Car volvo = new Volvo();
int newF = 10;

volvo.getEngine().getValve().setF(newF); // Done
```

Comment: Thanks. The Volvo case was an example.I needed a code that can give me a generic solution where there are many classes and strings like this one: "aClass.bClass.cClass.dClass.f"